# What is side effect in java streams API

Tags: java

What is meant by side-effects in Java Streams? Can you please explain me how to write functions without side-effects.

Comment: Refer https://codurance.com/2015/05/04/side-effects-and-java-8-streams/

Comment: Duplicate of question on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com: [What is a “side effect?”](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/40297/202153)

Comment: This is described in many places. You will get a better answer by searching.

Comment: check [the javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminal operations, such as Stream.forEach or IntStream.sum, may traverse the stream to produce a result or a side-effect

Please refer the below link to know more about side-effect.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html